# ImageBackground resizeMode not working in style props

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am developing a simple app in react native. i just started using react native. i am using latest version 0.64. problem is that resizeMode of ImageBackground is not working when used in stylesheet. however when i use it as direct props of ImageBackground components it starts working.

Following is my code:

```
/*global require */
...
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  useWindowDimensions,
    } from "react-native"; 

...

export default function LaunchScreen({ navigation }) {
 ...

  const image = require("../../assets/test.png");
 
  ...
  return (
    <View onLayout={handleLayout} style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground source={image} style={styles.image}>
     ...
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
...
  image: {
    flex: 1,

     resizeMode: "contain",//--> This is not working.
    justifyContent: "center",
  },


 ...
});

LaunchScreen.propTypes = {
  navigation: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

if i add this prop of resizeMode to ImageBackground it starts working.as per docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground it should work in stylesheet also. any idea why this is happening ?? and whats the solution

Comment: is it working with other resizeMode values?

Comment: no its not. not in stylesheet.

Comment: Try giving a height and width to the image instead of `flex:1`...it should work with that.

Comment: tried that, didn't work. May be its some kind of bug.

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/49309853/3237884 @BasitMinhas

Comment: Thanks @nazmul. This is poor documentation though by react-native. this should have been mentioned in docs. its not even mentioned in their example. anyways thanks. you can post this in answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below example for resizeMode,

```
<ImageBackground
              ...otherProps,
              resizeMode= 'contain'
            >
            {child}
        </ImageBackground>
```